# If a panic occurs within the http.HandlerFunc function, it will not be sent to the client http status code

Tags: http, go, panic

If a panic occurs within the http.HandlerFunc function, it will not be sent to the client http status code. Why is this and how can it be avoided? Because javascript XMLHttpRequest does not work well when it does not receive the http status code.

How do we write an ajax request for situations where the http response has no state and no body content?

```
func main() {
    var counter int

    http.HandleFunc("/hello", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        if counter%2 == 0 {
            counter++
            writer.Write([]byte(time.Now().String()))
        } else {
            counter++
            panic(":(")
        }
    })

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9999", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Don't use `panic` 2. If it's some other library - recover from panic then log and return `HTTP 500`

Comment: "it will not be sent to the client http status code" Why do you think this is true? What do you think happens? Have you tried? If you tried: What _did_ happen?

Answer (score 2):

You should not use a panic in this case.  Panic will cause the current go routine running the your handler func to exit without writing anything to the response which is not what you want, instead return an error code by using the `WriteHeader` method:

```
func main() {
    var counter int

    http.HandleFunc("/hello", func(writer http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
        if counter%2 == 0 {
            counter++
            writer.Write([]byte(time.Now().String()))
        } else {
            counter++
            writer.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        }
    })

    err := http.ListenAndServe(":9999", nil)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ResponseWriter

Comment: This is a good answer, but there is one little catch. `panic` causes the current go routine to exit. `http.ListenAndServe` starts multiple go routines to receive and process requests. Calling `panic` causes only the current call to the handler func to be exited. The program is still running and can process further http requests.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer @mbuechmann, answer has been updated to account for this.

Comment: @mbuechmann accurate in the case of `ListenAndServe`, but misleading. Normally `panic` causes the *entire program* to exit. However, `ListenAndServe` wraps the handler for each request in a goroutine with a `recover`, specifically to ensure that a `panic` in one request doesn't take down the  whole server; but this is *not* the normal behavior of `panic`. The normal behavior doesn't just stop the current goroutine, it crashes the whole process.

Comment: @Adrian Thanks. You are absolutely right. I oversimplified (due to my lack of knowledge).